# Proper way to trap in zsh script

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zsh, trap, macos

I'm having trouble getting a trap function in a zsh shell-script to work without exiting the shell. I have a simple countdown timer that I want to be able to interrupt using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and when I do I want the trap to change the cursor status in the terminal.

My syntax is:

```
trap 'tput cnorm; exit' INT TERM
```

I've also tried:

```
trap 'tput cnorm; kill -9 $$' INT TERM
```

both interrupts exit the shell entirely. How do I only exit the script  and return to the command line?

Any guidance will be most appreciated!

---

It's a shell script that will be an autoloaded function to be used in an interactive shell when it works.

Here's the entire script:

```
  #!/bin/zsh

  trap 'tput cnorm; exit' INT TERM

  tput civis

  duration=$(($1 * 60))
  start=$SECONDS
  time=1
  while [ $time -gt 0 ]; do
      output="$((duration - (SECONDS - start)))"
      sleep 1
      output=$(date -d@$time -u +%H:%M:%S)
      echo -ne "  $output     \r"
      done && echo -e "\033[2K"

  tput cnorm
```

Comment: Are you _sourcing_ your script? Using `kill -9` would definitely not be necessary. `exit` would only exit your shell if you source the script. Use `return` instead if that's the case.  Could you clarify if you're talking about a script, a script that you source, or a shell function that you run in an interactive shell, or whatever it may be?

Comment: I'm sourcing while I update it, but it will be an autoload function running in an interactive shell when it works.

Comment: Using  return 1 solved the issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Are you including the `trap` within a shell script, or are you typing it on the command line?  Consider, for example:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

interrupted=false
trap 'tput cnorm; interrupted=true' INT TERM

for ((i = 0; i < 100; ++i)); do
    clear
    date
    sleep 1

    if [[ "${interrupted}" = "true" ]]; then
        echo "Interrupted"
        break
    fi
done
```

With that I mimic a "countdown" with a delay loop that prints the time.  I can interrupt the "countdown".  I print "interrupted" just for illustration.

```
$ ./ex.zsh
Sat Jan 25 12:59:12 EST 2020
^CInterrupted
$
```

My example includes your `tput cnorm`, but doesn't really need it since I don't do anything to change it to begin with, but I include it to more closely match what you have in your question above.

Is this something close to what you're trying?

Comment: So would it be appropriate to use a break statement rather than an exit?

Comment: `exit` will terminate the script.  If you want to terminate the script, `exit` is fine.  In my example above I set state that I checked in a loop, and used that to terminate the script.  It all depends on what you want to do when.

Comment: So It works if I make it executable, but this shouldn't be necessary if I use it as an autoload function, right?

Comment: how to terminate the program started via the zsh script?